# Why is there a white "loading screen" before my page transitions in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I finally got my page transition animation working correctly (it slides from the bottom to the top of the screen) but for some reason there is a blank white "loading screen" that appears before the page does and it is ruining the whole point of the sliding animation!  Can someone please tell me how to get rid of this white screen?!

Please see a video I made of this:  https://youtu.be/92XGji7L-RU

```
const { height: deviceHeight } = Dimensions.get('window');

class OrdersScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            offset: new Animated.Value(deviceHeight),
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Animated.timing(this.state.offset, {
          duration: 350,
          toValue: 0,
        }).start();
    }

    closeModal() {
        Animated.timing(this.state.offset, {
          duration: 350,
          toValue: -deviceHeight,
        }).start(Actions.pop);
    }

    searchOrders = searchTerm => {
        this.props.dispatch(searchOrdersWithStatus(this.props.orderStatus, searchTerm))
    }

    render() {
        // default to Active Orders
        const status = this.props.orderStatus || ORDER_TYPE_DELIVERIES;
        let title = 'Order History';

        if (ORDER_TYPE_DELIVERIES == status) {
            title = 'Orders';
        }

        if (ORDER_TYPE_ISSUES == status) {
            title = 'Item Alerts';
        }

        return (
            <Animated.View style={[styles.wrapper, { transform: [{ translateY: this.state.offset }] }]}>
                <OrderHeader title={title} enableBack={false} />

                <FullWidthSearchBar placeholder='Search Orders' changeCallback={this.searchOrders} timeoutMillis={500} />

                <OrderSummaryList orderStatus={status} />
            </Animated.View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    wrapper: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start'
    }
});
```

Comment: This could be just a simulator problem - have you tried running the app on a physical device?

Comment: Yes, I have tested it on a physical device and it still does it =/

Comment: I'm guessing you're using react-native-flux. I'm not sure if the library has any way of defining modals but if it does, I'd probably recommend using that.

That being said, have you tried using the native driver (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated#using-the-native-driver)? Also, there is no reason to keep the animated value in state, but that does not affect the performance.

Comment: Seem's some css issue. Have you tried to set the some fallback/or default height and width to your component. also for position absolute you have to use the z-index.

Comment: Please clarify what navigation library you are using or if you are using react natives default navigation

Comment: Please post OrderSummaryList  code

Answer (score 0):

Your `<OrderSummaryList />` component probably loads data from API - it takes some time ... on initial render data is not ready yet ... render shows `' component. This "content" is animated ... later data arrives and content is rerendered.

You can try to delay animation on start - using `.delay(miliseconds)` instead of `start()` in `componentDidMount()`. Find required time experimentally - too short can show loading (slow connection), too long will look like not responding app.